# SQL UNION query returns first row with column names

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I am in a situation where I use UNION to combine my queries. But the problem is that the first row is duplicate of column names like so:

[image]

What I am doing wrong? If I do not decalre row names statically in my first part then I get different number of columns error. This is my query:

```
SELECT "id"
     , "place_id"
     , [...]
     , (SELECT Count(pl.payment_method = 'PREPAID_CREDIT' )) AS prepaid_transactions
     , [...]
UNION
SELECT ps.id AS id
     , p.id AS place_id
     , [...]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first query has no values for the columns that you've declared as strings, you can use `NULL` there instead. e.g;

```
SELECT NULL AS id
     , NULL AS place_id
     , [...]
     , (SELECT Count(pl.payment_method = 'PREPAID_CREDIT' )) AS prepaid_transactions
     , [...]
UNION
SELECT ps.id AS id
     , p.id AS place_id
     , [...]
```

and so on. All you really need to worry about is that both sides of the `UNION` have the same number of columns (and that the data in each column matches up).

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting strings:

```
SELECT "id", "place_id", "client_id",...
```

You should select the actual column values from whichever table the data comes from

```
SELECT ps.id, p.place_id, p.client_id,...
```

Comment: But in that case wouldn't it be the same query with additional selects? If for example you take row named `location` then in my first query what should be the location value?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "same query with additional selects". If you select strings you get strings, if you select the columns, you get the column values. As for the `location`, where do you expect the value for `location` to come from?

Comment: I mean that I can not use the second query's `as xxx` as a row value in my first query select. I would declare them as nulls in my first query but in that case all row names would be NULLs. And with "same query with additional selects" I mean that I would have to make same selects in my first query if I do like you say.

Comment: The second part of the query (2nd part of the UNION) has nothing to do with the first part. Both queries produce a result set which the UNION then combines. Fix the first query as there you are selecting the strings instead of column values. You can run the first part of the query separately and see the result.